# vb.net - exception handling not working when reading regkey

Tags: vb.net, exception, registry, nullreferenceexception

I have a function 'ReadRegValue' in my code...

```
 Public Function ReadRegValue(ByRef location As String, ByRef value As String)
    Try
        Console.WriteLine(location)
        Dim thisvalue As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(location, value, vbnull).ToString
        Return thisvalue
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return vbNull
    End Try
 End Function
```

This has been working fine until I ran my project on a device where one of the keys doesn't exist because a particular program isn't installed on that system.

In this case, it threw an exception - NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I understand the exception and the reason behind it, ie the key doesnt exist so how can it be read; but I  was expecting it to return null in the event that a key wasn't present or any other exception was thrown.

Can anyone help shed some light on why this exception wasn't caught in the Try Catch or where I may have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `vbNull`?  Why is no return type given for `ReadRegValue`?  Are you sure that the exception isn't caught?  You might have exception settings set to break when the exception is thrown (this is a good idea), in which case you would break in the debugger but it would still be caught.  Are you sure that the issue is a nullrefexception issuing from within the Try/Catch, vs. an exception issuing from trying to return `vbNull` or an exception from the code that calls `ReadRegValue`?

Comment: @Craig you are spot on... it is catching the exception but breaking anyway.

Comment: *feels silly*.  So vbnull is what is returned if anything goes wrong in the function, it is also the default value supplied if the value doesnt exist... so essentially it starts of with null/nothing and ends up with null/nothing unless the key and value exist, in which case it returns the value.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: That looks like VB6 code. Turn `Option Strict On`. Specify the return type of the method. Stop declaring parameters `ByRef` for no reason. Stop using `vbNull` and use `Nothing` to represent no object.

Comment: I've been caught out by that before, even after years of routinely having very aggressive break-on-thrown settings.

Answer (score 0):

Exception was being handled, but exception settings were set to break on nullreferenceexception, so it appeared to be bombing out, but wasn't actually misbehaving.